# MFC CFindFile::FindNextFile usage

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc

The documentation for CFindFile states that

> Nonzero if there are more files; zero
>   if the file found is the last one in
>   the directory or if an error occurred.
>   To get extended error information,
>   call the Win32 function GetLastError.
>   If the file found is the last file in
>   the directory, or if no matching files
>   can be found, the GetLastError
>   function returns ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES.

So how do I know if I have 1 file or 0 files if a call to FindNextFile returns the same value?

It seems that a call to FindFile::GetFilePath() fails (which inadvertently causes my application to crash) if zero files are found.

```
pLog->Log(_T("Finding files in [%s]"), 1, szFilePath);

    if (!oFindFile.FindFile(szFilePath, 0))
{
    pLog->Log(_T("Failed to find file in directory: [%s]"),1,szDirectory);
    return false;
}

bool moreFiles = true;
while(moreFiles)
{
    moreFiles = oFindFile.FindNextFile();
    if (oFindFile.IsDots())
    {
        continue;
    }

    CString szFileName = oFindFile.GetFilePath();
    pLog->Log(_T("Found file [%s]"), 1, szFileName);
    pVector->push_back(szFileName);
}
return true;
```

**Edit**

```
CString szFilePath = _T("C:\documents and settings\username\desktop\*.lnk");
CString szDirectory = T("C:\documents and settings\username\desktop");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are no files, your call to `CFileFind::FindFile` will return false. You need to call this before you can call `FindNextFile`.

Comment: Hmmm alright. I am calling that function. Maybe I'm doing something else wrong...

Comment: Sure. The first log statement is called but the second (within the if block) is not called.

Comment: What is the content of szFilePath and szDirectory?

Comment: Wait....hold your horses. I think I know what it is and it has to do with szDirectory...

Comment: Missing the double backslash \\ ?

Comment: There are 0 matches in the directory. It happens that szDirectory actually had unexpanded envrionment variables in it; which for some reason was killing the logging mechanism. That is why there is no log :). Thanks for the trouble shooting ideas though it really helped me track this down. Now to look at this stupid logging stuff..

Answer (score 2):

The documentation also states that if you get a 0 return code from "FindNextFile", you should call "GetLastError()" to see if it equals "ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES". It's still not entirely clear to me that a 0 return code means "I found one more file, so process it," versus "I didn't find any files, so don't call the other API's or you'll crash."

I think Microsoft needs to rethink this class to be "1" means I found a file, and "0" means I didn't find a file. Then, the code could be written like this:

(Disclaimer: DO NOT USE THIS CODE! IT IS WRONG! YOU WILL SKIP ONE FILE EACH TIME!)

```
CFileFind cff;
if ( cff.FindFile(_T("*.*")) )
{
    while ( cff.FindNextFile() )
    {
        // Use the API's here without fear of crashing...
    }
    cff.Close();
}
```

But, that's not how they designed this class. I guess the bottom line is: Use at your own risk.

P.S. Just to be clear, the code above is not how this class is designed to work. PLEASE DO NOT USE THE CODE ABOVE!!!!